# Decode a top command

Tags: linux

This output is from the TOP command on a debian machine

```
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.8%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
```

I think I figured out what most of the values in this menu option

- us = user process
- sy = system process
- id = idle process

What are the rest of the values here?

Answer (score 5):

From the horses mouth (`man top`):

2c. CPU States
       The CPU states are shown in the Summary Area. They are always shown as a percentage and are for the time between now and the last refresh.

```
    us  --  User CPU time
      The time the CPU has spent running users' processes that are not niced.

    sy  --  System CPU time
      The time the CPU has spent running the kernel and its processes.

    ni  --  Nice CPU time
      The time the CPU has spent running users' proccess that have been niced.

    wa  --  iowait
      Amount of time the CPU has been waiting for I/O to complete.

    hi  --  Hardware IRQ
      The amount of time the CPU has been servicing hardware interrupts.

    si  --  Software Interrupts
      The amount of time the CPU has been servicing software interrupts.

    st  --  Steal Time
      The amount of CPU 'stolen' from this virtual machine by the hypervisor for other tasks (such as running another virtual machine).
```